# Concatenate to reference variable?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'll start by saying I am a novice coder.  I get by.  I am making a Google Sheet with scripting and I have a need to reference varibales that are numbered.  I am trying to reduce code and wonder if you are able to do something like this (keep in mind this is dumbed down code as an example.

```
var range1 = sheet.getRange("A1:A10");
var range2 = sheet.getRange("B1:B10");
var value = 1;

sheet.getRange(range + value).getValues();
```

So instead of having to use range 1 and range 2, I would use range + value and the value would be set elsewhere.  I have attempted the above and it did not work but I am not sure if there is another way or if you just cannot do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add a number to a [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object. To get another range that is bigger or smaller than the original range, use [Range.offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows,-numcolumns), like this:

```js
function test() {
  const range = sheet.getRange('A1:A10');
  const height = range.getHeight();
  const width = range.getWidth();
  const heightIncrement = 1;
  const values = range.offset(0, 0, height + heightIncrement, width).getValues();
  console.log(values);
}
```

Comment: You could also add it as a string to the A1Notation of the range